# Of what type should a superclass be when using a subclass factory pattern in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, subclass, factory

I'm trying to implement a subclass factory pattern in TypeScript 3.x.
Consider this test:

```
import { expect } from 'chai'

describe('subclass factory', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    interface INameable {
      name?: string
    }

    const name = 'I am a Nameable!'

    function nameableSubclassOf<T> (superclass) {
      return class extends superclass implements INameable {
        name?: string = name
      }
    }

    class Foo {}

    const NameableFoo = nameableSubclassOf(Foo)
    const nameableFoo = new NameableFoo()

    expect(nameableFoo).to.be.instanceOf(Foo)
    expect(nameableFoo.name).to.be.ok
    expect(nameableFoo.name).to.equal(name)
  })
})
```

Compilation fails with the following message:

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
>
> src/test/subclass-factory.ts(11,37): error TS7006: Parameter 'superclass' implicitly has an 'any' type.

How do I change the above code to successfully compile and return a `class` that is a subclass of `T` that also declares that it implements `INameable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your choices are either to tell Typescript that `superclass` is `new`able, the syntax for which is [briefly alluded to in the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics):

```
// "new (...args: any[]) => any" means the constructor takes any number of arguments 
// and returns anything

function nameableSubclassOf<C extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(superclass: C) {
  return class extends superclass implements INameable {
    name?: string = name
  }
}
```

This should allow the compiler to infer a usable, but fairly opaque type for the return value of `nameableSubclassOf`:

```
const NameableFoo = nameableSubclassOf(Foo)
// const NameableFoo: {
//   new (...args: any[]): nameableSubclassOf<typeof Foo>.(Anonymous class);
//   prototype: nameableSubclassOf<any>.(Anonymous class);
// } & typeof Foo 

const nameableFoo = new NameableFoo();
// const nameableFoo: nameableSubclassOf2<typeof Foo>.(Anonymous class) & Foo; 

const fooName = nameableFoo.name;
// const fooName: string | undefined;
```

---

... or, if you want a more explicit type that doesn't rely on anonymous classes, you can use generics to specify the superclass and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to extract the constructor argument and return types from it:

```
function nameableSubclassOf<C extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(
  superclass: C
): C extends new (...args: infer A) => infer T ? new (...args: A) => T & INameable : never;
function nameableSubclassOf(
  superclass: new (...args: any[]) => any
): new (...args: any[]) => INameable {
  return class extends superclass implements INameable {
    name?: string = name
  }
}
```

Note that I used a single [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) for the function call signature, which is what the caller sees.  The implementation signature is looser because it's hard for the compiler to verify that a value is assignable to a conditional type... so the one-signature-overload is a way to get more type safety for the caller of a function without having to use loads of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) in the implementation.

That's more verbose, but when you use it you get nicer types:

```
const NameableFoo = nameableSubclassOf(Foo)
// const NameableFoo: new () => Foo & INameable 

const nameableFoo = new NameableFoo()
// const nameableFoo: Foo & INameable 

const fooName = nameableFoo.name
// const fooName: string | undefined
```

---

Hope one of those helps.  Good luck!

Comment: That's some awesome voodoo metamagic that actually allows my tests to pass.  Can we make this a learning moment and have you explain it?  The part that's trippin' my brain out specifically is `function nameableSubclassOf<C extends new (...args: any[]) => any> (superclass: C):
      C extends new (...args: infer A) => infer T
        ? new (...args: A) => T & INameable
        : never`, which looks to be a `function` with no body, unless my brain's TypeScript parser is messed up.

Comment: I've been working on trait support in TypeScript using this subclass factory pattern at https://github.com/matthewadams/typescript-trait/pull/2. @jcalz, would you mind collaborating on it with me?  Specifically, I'd like to generalize the solution one more level, so that the interface that gets implemented is variable.

Comment: Regarding voodoo metamagic, I updated the answer to describe how I'm using a single-signature [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

Comment: Regarding making the implemented interface variable... what would you be passing to the function other than the superclass?  Would it be two classes?  Or a class and a [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html)  (in which case are you doing something significantly different from the mixin stuff on that page)?

Answer (score 0):

This way?

```
function nameableSubclassOf(superclass: {new(): any}) {
```